# Can't install latest numpy and scipy under virtual environment

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, python-venv

I have been struggling to upgrade/install numpy and scipy to the latest versions under my venv. The reason for wanting to upgrade is the error when running my script under venv:

```
(venv)[malapradej@lotus Code]$ python2.7 create_emulator_ap_680-755.py --sza 80 --vza 80 --raa 180 --train /work/scratch/malapradej/DASF/Data/LUT_ap/lhd250_train_ap1 --validate /work/scratch/malapradej/DASF/Data/LUT_ap/lhd300_valid_ap1 --plot n

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_emulator_ap_680-755.py", line 57, in <module>
    import gp_emulator
  File "/home/users/malapradej/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages /gp_emulator/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from multivariate_gp import MultivariateEmulator
  File "/home/users/malapradej/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gp_emulator/multivariate_gp.py", line 32, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/home/users/malapradej/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import _conv
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv (/tmp/pip-build-JA5F4M/h5py/h5py/_conv.c:6970)
  File "h5py/h5t.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5t (/tmp/pip-build-JA5F4M/h5py/h5py/h5t.c:19707)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Under venv I ran:

```
pip install -Iv numpy==1.10.1
```

and

```
pip install -Iv --upgrade numpy==1.10.1
```

Each time it ends with:

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.7.0
Cleaning up...
```

when I use yolk to see what packages are used:

```
yolk -l | grep numpy

numpy           - 1.10.1       - non-active
numpy           - 1.7.0        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages)
numpy           - 1.9.2        - non-active
```

I seems to have downloaded the package but won't upgrade and active it.

If I run ipython it seems to work:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: print np.__version__
1.10.1
```

But under python2.7 it show the earlier version:

```
(venv)[malapradej@cems-sci1 venv]$ python2.7

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.0'
```

The same for scipy.

Help much appreciated,

Comment: Can you paste your PYTHONPATH variable? (echo $PYTHONPATH)

Comment: There is noting in the PYTHONPATH variable both with and without activating the venv.

Comment: Try locating where numpy 1.10.1 was installed and adding the directory where it resides to `PYTHONPATH`, as in `export PYTHONPATH=$(PYTHONPATH):path_to_numpy_1.10.1`(That's in the same prompt you're going to run Python from)

Comment: Using `import sys; sys.path` shows `['/home/users/malapradej/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/users/malapradej/.ipython']`
It is located is in `/home/users/malapradej/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: After exporting the PYTHONPATH as suggested and reinstalling using `pip install --upgrade numpy==1.10.1` I get `InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.7.0
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages, outside environment /home/users/malapradej/venv`

Comment: I tried it and it returns `Successfully installed numpy-1.7.0
Cleaning up...` every time.

Comment: Within your virtualenv, what do `which ipython`, `which pip` and `which python2.7` return?

Comment: `which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
which pip
~/venv/bin/pip
which python2.7
~/venv/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative I had was to delete the old virtualenv and re-install using `virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/venv`  and all packages again using `pip install --upgrade <package>`. It seems like somewhere the venv got corrupted and trying to figure out where this occurred would have take too long.